# Me sale el siguiente error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" al momento de querer crear mi virtual host en windows

Tags: windows, xampp, virtualhost

Lo que quiero hacer es un virtual host para que mi sitio web no tenga la url "localhost:8080", pero me sale el siguiente error:

Código de C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    #127.0.0.1       delaguila.pe
    ::8080  www.league.mx
```

Codigo de C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin www.league.mx
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/League/trunk/public"
    ServerName www.league.mx
    ServerAlias www.league.mx
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/League/trunk/public">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all        
     </Directory>
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

La url que pongo en mi navegador es la siguiente www.league.mx o www.league.mx:8080 y el resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esta configuración de de C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
      DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/League/trunk/public"
      ServerName www.league.mx
      ServerAlias league.mx
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/League/trunk/public">
         AllowOverride All
         Require all Granted      
     </Directory>
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

y esta en C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
    # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    #127.0.0.1       localhost
    #::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       www.league.mx
```

Comment: Oye ya intente tu respuesta en mi codigo y si funciono pero con variantes, esto quiere decir que no acepto la url www.league.mx y si la league.localhost pero ademas necesitaba poner el puerto 8080 para que ingresara si no lo ponia me salia el error 404 not found y yo necesito que sea sin el puerto 8080 en la url

Comment: ummm... Pues lo único que se me ocurre es que pruebes con el puerto 80. Yo es el que uso y a mi esta configuración me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

en el archivo host usa

```
localhost::8080  www.league.mx
```

y en virtual host httpd-vhosts

```
<VirtualHost www.league.mx:8080>
    ServerAdmin www.league.mx
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/League/trunk/public"
    ServerName www.league.mx
    ServerAlias www.league.mx
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/League/trunk/public">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all        
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```